# Xamarin.iOS with MVVMCross call only constructors at ViewControllers

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Does anybody face this problem? I'm trying to implement MVVM using MVVMCross in Xamarin.iOS project, but in ViewController only constructor was called, neither ViewDidLoad nor ViewWillAppear. What's wrong? Or may be I miss something? Thank you.

```
public partial class VideosViewController : MvxViewController<VideoListViewModel>
{      
    public VideosViewController() : base(nameof(VideosViewController), null)
    {

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();            
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }
}

public class VideoListViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IVideoService _videoService;
    public CancellationTokenSource TokenSource => new CancellationTokenSource();

    public VideoListViewModel(IVideoService videoService)
    {
        _videoService = videoService;
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await base.Initialize();                  
    }
}
```

Comment: If something is wrong, MvvmCross usually produces some very descriptive console output. Can you have a look at the console output?

Comment: Last message is "PresentationAttribute nor MasterNavigationController found for VideosViewController. Assuming Root presentation"

Comment: Could not make sure  if it is an existing issue of the library . But since you had used MVVM , you would better handle the logic in ViewModel. Starting with MvvmCross 5.0, ViewModels will be coupled to the lifecycle of the view. This means that the ViewModel has the following methods available:`void ViewCreated();

void ViewAppearing();

void ViewAppeared();` .Check https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle

Comment: Try to add attribute to your controller: [MvxRootPresentation]  or [MvxChildPresentation]

Comment: What @LucasZhang-MSFT suggests might be a legit work around. But I have seen before that `ViewDidLoad` was not triggered and the solution was to do restart Visual Studio, do a clean/rebuild. Worth a try if you haven't already.